# Checking pointer of *char[] is NULL without upsetting gcc

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, syntax, null

I have `char *words[]` that holds strings of varying length.

Let `words` contain 5 dynamically allocated strings: `["zero","one","two","three","four"]`.

I free one of the strings and set its pointer to `NULL` like so:

```
free(words[1]);
*(words[1]) = NULL;
```

Later on I loop through the `words` array and check if each item is `NULL` like so:

```
if(*words[i] == NULL)
```

And when I compile gcc says `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`.  A bit of googling has shown me that I can silence this warning by changing the check to:

`if(*words[i] == 0)` or `if(*words[i])`

I know its nitpicky, but these checks just aren't as clear as it would be if it used `NULL`.  Is there a way to compare using `NULL` without altering gcc flags or using a `#define`-esque solution?

---

As a reference, my compile command is:

```
gcc -m32 -g -O0 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wfloat-equal -Wtype-limits -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -fno-diagnostics-show-option  -m32  words.c   -o words
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code isn't doing what you think it is. `*words[i]` gives you the first character in the ith string (i.e. a `char`), not the ith string itself (i.e. a `char*`). What you want is just `words[i]`. Remember that in C `char* words[]` is basically `char** words`.

The warning comes from the fact that C considers `char` to be an integer. In this case, it is a good thing the compiler warned you!

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to test this really quick then, assuming you're right, I'll approve your answer